# Colorbar ticks formatting does not work

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code which produces a scatter plot with a colorbar:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
from matplotlib.ticker import *
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from list2nparr import list2nparr

# this part changes the fonts for latex handling
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{lmodern}"]
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'lmodern'
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 16
#==================================================================
fig,ax1 = plt.subplots()
data = list2nparr('radiant.txt')
lm  = data[:,14]
bet = data[:,15]
b   = data[:,18]
#
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet')
sc2 = ax1.scatter(lm, bet, c=b, s=10, cmap=cm, edgecolor='none',rasterized=True)
# ==========================COLORBAR SPECS=========================
cb3 = fig.colorbar(sc2,ax = ax1, aspect=10)
cb3.ax.tick_params(labelsize=16)
cb3.set_label(r'$\beta = F_R/F_G$',size=18,labelpad=20)
cb3.formatter.set_powerlimits((0, 0))
cb3.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5,prune='upper')) # WHY DOES THIS LINE NOT WORK?
cb3.update_ticks()

# =======================SCATTER PLOT SPECS========================
ax1.set_ylabel('$b$, (deg)',fontsize=18,labelpad=0.5)
ax1.set_xlabel("$\lambda-\lambda_{\odot}$, (deg)",fontsize=18)
plt.savefig('test.eps', format='eps')
```

At some point, I am trying to format the ticks of the colorbar, requesting only five ticks while removing the uppermost label. This is illustrated in line 30, where it says: `cb3.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5,prune='upper'))`

However, this line seems to have no effect on the plot at all?
Any ideas what might be the reason for that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

Use the locator when you create the colorbar:

```
cb3 = fig.colorbar(sc2,ax = ax1, aspect=10, ticks=MaxNLocator(5))
```

and remove this line:

```
cb3.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5,prune='upper'))
```

### Old answers

Flip the order of these two lines:

```
cb3.update_ticks()
cb3.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5,prune='upper'))
```

and you should only five color intervals.

Alternatively, don't use `set_major_locator` at all and set the ticks directly in when making an instance:

```
cb3 = fig.colorbar(sc2,ax = ax1, aspect=10, ticks=[0, 2.5e-4, 5e-4, 7.5e-4, 1e-3 ])
```

Comment: it seems to work but it clobbers the range of the errorbar, so it does not solve the problem. 
Initially my errorbar had a range from 0.0 -2.25 but not it seems to run from 0.0 to 1.25. I wish there was a way to show the two images so you could compare them.

Comment: You can add images to a question. Just click on the icon that looks like an image, than drag and drop.

Comment: Sorry, I am kind of new to stack overflow, so I don't know where the image icon is. I can't see it?

Comment: I uploaded the two images to my original question. The first image is after the suggestion to place 
`cb3.update_ticks()` before the call to the formatter and the second image is the original one. Clearly the range in the first image has been clobbered.

Comment: Try  without `prune='upper'`:  `cb3.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5))`.

Comment: I tried it, and now the value of 1.25 is the last (top) value of the colorbar. But originally it shouid run from 0.0 to 2.25. So some values have been lost.

Comment: The suggested alternative works when I disable MaxNLocator. However, the snippet that I showed is a part of a larger code which in turn is a part of a toolkit. There is no way for me to know apriori the exact values of the colorbar (they are not constant). So, it would be nice if matplotlib could select 5 bins based on my data. So, the alternative is not the right solution for me.

Comment: Hi @Mike,
Yes, I confirm that the edit works. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @user3578925 Great that it helped. BTW, you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem. Also, you have the privilege to [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). ;)